# Why parameter aProcesses set 1024 in EnumProcesses?

Tags: delphi, process, window

I use EnumProcesses to get process and I just find all the example set aProcesses equal to 1024 or 1024*2

[delphi] code like this :

```
uses PsAPI;

var
  cbNeeded : DWORD;
  aProcesses : array[0..1024] of DWORD;
begin

  EnumProcesses(@aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded);
  //use PID do something

end;
```

so my question is why set aProcesses equal to 1024 , 1024 is the max number of processes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that PsAPI is using the Win32 method of the same name ([`EnumProcesses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN), 1024 is an attempt to use a number that is larger than the number of processes running on the machine at one time. If you look in the remarks for the linked function, you will see that it says:

> To determine how many processes were enumerated, divide the pBytesReturned value by sizeof(DWORD). There is no indication given when the buffer is too small to store all process identifiers. Therefore, if pBytesReturned equals cb, consider retrying the call with a larger array.